# saving multiple plots from a loop in pdf

Tags: python, pdf, plot, save

I have big datasets in which I am plotting and fitting in a loop x (df_time) vs y (all the columns in df_intensity. I would like to save all the plots generated with the fit but I dont seem to manage, I only manage to display them.

I am also getting a line below the plot that may indicate what the problem is but I couldnt find an alternative. Is there a way of easily implementing a save as pdf in a way that I get multiple plots per page (I am generating hundreds so I suposse that I will need multiple pages, so ideally is something that automatically saves it in a pdf and when the page is full it goes to the next.
Many thanks!

```
fname must be a PathLike or file handle
```

I am using the following code:

```
coefficients=[]
for column in df_intensity:
    try:
        plt.scatter(df_time01, column)
        plt.show()
# starting point for the decay to fit
        decay_start = np.argmax(column)
# use only decay points in the fit
        guess = [1, 0.001, 0]

        popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, df_time01[decay_start:],
                           column[decay_start:],
                           p0=guess)

# get the fit curve
    #try:
        fit = func(df_time01[decay_start:], *popt)

# plot the fit and data
        plt.plot(df_time01[decay_start:], fit, label='fit', c='r')
        plt.scatter(df_time01, column, label='data')
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
        print('Fit parameters: {}'.format(popt))
        coefficients.append(popt)
        plt.savefig(column, dpi=300, transparent=True)  
        with PdfPages('multipage_pdf.pdf') as pdf:
            plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
            plt.plot
            plt.title('Page One')
            pdf.savefig()  # saves the current figure into a pdf page
            plt.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Error - curve_fit failed")
        continue
```

Comment: You should use `plt.show()` after `pdf.savefig()`. Otherwise you're not saving anything into the PDF. Also `fname` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in your code so it's difficult to tell what that is.